# Installing DRBD on Redhat 5

Tags: rhel, drbd

I am trying to install DRBD on Redhat 5. Everything i find is out of date, and all the files are not hosted anymore. From what I understand I need to install the Cent OS repositories to install DRBD on Redhat 5?

Can anyone lead me in the right direction with this please?

I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DRBD is available in the [ELRepo](http://elrepo.org/tiki/tiki-index.php).

To install in RHEL 5, run the following:

```
rpm --import http://elrepo.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-elrepo.org
rpm -Uvh http://elrepo.org/elrepo-release-5-3.el5.elrepo.noarch.rpm
yum update
yum search drbd
```

Comment: Great! Glad to help.